# Have to manually refresh page to make right alert come up

Tags: javascript, forms, alert

I have written a function in which part of it validates a user's input to a form (see that part of the function below). My whole program currently works, EXCEPT that now, if there is one alert that comes up (for example, if I don't fill in one of the boxes on the form and "All fields are required!") alerts, if I then input incorrect information into that box (where now "Make sure to input valid information!" should alert), instead it keeps prompting with "All fields are required!" from the last invalid entry, rather than assessing the current problem. The only way to get it to assess the current invalid input and give the correct second alert is to manually refresh the page. Anyone have idea why that is or what I can do to get it so that I don't have to manually refresh?

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    if (validateInput(pilot) === "Empty" || validateInput(copilot) === "Empty" || validateInput(fuelLevel) === "Empty" || validateInput(cargoMass) === "Empty") {
        event.preventDefault()
        window.alert("All fields are required!");
    } else if (validateInput(pilot) === "Is a Number" || validateInput(copilot) === "Is a Number" || validateInput(fuelLevel) === "Not a Number" || validateInput(cargoMass) === "Not a Number") {
        event.preventDefault()
        window.alert("Make sure to enter valid information for each field!")
    } else { // other code to update part of the page with the user input
```

Comment: to refresh a page use `location.reload();`

Comment: Thanks Andri, location.reload() didn't fix it because it actually seems like the problem is that the form isn't capturing the new value input by the user, once that user says "OK" to the alert and then tries to input a new, correct response. I need to figure out how to capture the new value entered by the user

Comment: save them in a variable